# Is it possible to pass variables via markdown to a typescript file?

Tags: angular, typescript, markdown

This is more a pre-project question. Say I'm making a blog site where each entry is written in a .md file. Can I make it so the author has the ability to add some kind of custom tag which allows them to change the display of the site (like maybe the navbar animates/displays differently for a politics entry vs a personal entry).

If not, is there an easy way I can make something like that possible, where custom display parameters are saved in conjunction with the actual .md file? For what I'm planning it'd have to be able to take in several different variables for multiple different functions on the page.

Mostly I've been looking into how markdown works, and have struggled to use the right search parameters. Or I may be trying to straight up do what markdown is not meant to do.

Comment: You can query for `front matter markdown`. (The term comes from [book design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_design#Front_matter).) Any front matter will need to be parsed from the markdown using a text parser.

Comment: Thank you so much! Front matter is exactly the term I was looking for, I just couldn't find it. I really appreciate it!